# Finding root cause for out of memory killer

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

Recently, I stumbled upon this error which, I can understand happening because of Out Of Memory , but not sure who is requesting memory.

```
[ 8539.677000] syslog-ng invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
[ 8539.677000] syslog-ng cpuset=demo_app mems_allowed=0
[ 8539.678000] [ 2930]   102  2930     2893     1702   0       0             0 syslog-ng
[ 8539.678000] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 2930 (syslog-ng) score 83 or sacrifice child
[ 8539.678000] Killed process 2930 (syslog-ng) total-vm:11572kB, anon-rss:6768kB, file-rss:40kB
```

From this line `[ 8539.677000] syslog-ng cpuset=demo_app mems_allowed=0` does it mean `demo_app` is requesting more memory?

what is cpuset anyway, can i use any information here to find the root cause for this error?

**Update OS and Version:**

```
# cat /etc/issue
Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.0 \n \l
# uname -a
Linux CHB 3.2.48 #1 SMP Tue Mar 14 15:52:38 CET 2017 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What's your OS? Version? Who installed and configured it?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, Updated the post, Me saying **_sorry_** for not providing that info before hand will not justify my mistake but, I was really unaware that info required, I thought its common problem in any Linux and was not asking for internal details just want to know any of those details given above will be used to identify problem or can i really find out who is culprit.

Comment: What you're observing is not very common and I've no idea what your distro is and how it's set up but it's not an average distro. Also, the kernel release is incredibly old. What's the device you're running?